# Line Chart through server database using json

Tags: android, mysql, json, database

I want to make line chart through getting data from database server using json. As i am making app for patients where he can see his BP, Sugar graph with values and date in graph. Please help to get rid out of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For you to create such kind of applications, you are supposed to have a minimum knowledge in php and mysql. This link can help you to learn how to fetch data from mysql database to your application using php.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/